# What is required for user to accept CKShare?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I am trying to share records between users on CloudKit but I'm having trouble allowing users to accept shares. When a user opens a share on their device, their status on the share continues to show up as "invited" rather than switching to "accepted." The UserDidAcceptCloudkitShare function does not get called.

**Am I wrong to think that opening a share is equivalent to accepting?** If so, what is the trick to having a user *accept* a share?

Please excuse my ignorance, as I'm new to CloudKit and iOS in general. Thanks.